# ISCN- from genomic coordinates

Tags: r, genomicranges

I got a large table with genomic coordinates of CNV found in our cohort:

```
CNV
```

```
chr1:146458850-148003653
```

I would like to add the following data to the table :
International System for Human Cytogenetic Nomenclature(ISCN), cnv size, names of genes /amount of genes in the genomic region, amount of OMIM genes and OMIM description:

```
CNV   ISCN geneName num_genes num_omim_genes omim_num omim_name
```

```
chr1:146458850-148003653 1.q.21.1 NEGR1 1 1 613173 NEURONAL GROWTH REGULATOR 1; NEGR1
```

What is the best program/tool/package for this? Maybe an R package?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, hg19 version for the position of a chromosome band found in this file: http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/database/cytoBand.txt.gz

OMIM info for hg19 data from NCBI:
        ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov//genomes/H_sapiens/ARCHIVE/ANNOTATION_RELEASE.105/GFF/ref_GRCh37.p13_top_level.gff3.gz